# Display datepicker calendar without dropdown button?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

In a C# 4.5 WPF window I would like to add a `DatePicker` but in a calendar style so without any visible `TextBox` or `DropDown` button. A simple calendar view with the possibility to select a date. No need for typing a date.

I've done something similar in previous web projects:

[image: date picker web style]

It seems so simple but I can't find any examples and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

My god this is shameful.. I was looking to customize the `Datepicker` control but there is just a `Calendar` control in the default wpf controls.

So erhm... case closed..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<toolkit:Calendar x:Name="_calendar" DisplayModeChanged="_calendar_DisplayModeChanged" DisplayMode="Year" />
with the code behind
Private Sub _calendar_DisplayModeChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Windows.Controls.CalendarModeChangedEventArgs)

    If _calendar.DisplayMode = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Month Then
        _calendar.DisplayMode = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Year
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: 'toolkit' is not recognized in visual studio... Am I missing some reference or namespace?

Comment: toolkit is a namespace declaration to a ... toolkit .. probably something like this:  http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Okay, that explains a lot :-)  So this basic calendar visualisation is not possible at all in .NET basic controls?